# putting Filter and Consumer in the same scope (MassTransit)

Tags: filter, dependency-injection, masstransit

**Startup Class**

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(CustomTransactionFilter<>));
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumers(typeof(OrderStateOrchestrator).Assembly);

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(massTransitOption.HostName,
                 massTransitOption.VirtualHost,
                 hst =>
                 {
                     hst.Username(massTransitOption.UserName);
                     hst.Password(massTransitOption.Password);
                 });
        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(CustomTransactionFilter<>), context);
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{Program.STARTUP_PROJECT_NAME}.{nameof(OrderStateOrchestrator)}",
                            endpointConfigurator => { endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumer<OrderStateOrchestrator>(context); });
    });
});
```

**FilterClass**

```
public class CustomTransactionFilter<T> :
        IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> where T : class
{
    private readonly IIntegrationMessagePublisher _integrationMessagePublisher;
    
    public CustomTransactionFilter(IIntegrationMessagePublisher integrationMessagePublisher)
    {
        _integrationMessagePublisher = integrationMessagePublisher;
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        await next.Send(context);
        Console.WriteLine($"TransactionFilter - {typeof(T).Namespace} : {_integrationMessagePublisher.IntegrationMessages.Count}");
        await _integrationMessagePublisher.Publish();
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

**Consumer Class**

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<PaymentCompletedEvent> context)
{
    PaymentCompletedEvent paymentCompletedEvent = context.Message;
    long orderId = long.Parse(paymentCompletedEvent.CorrelationId)

    await _distributedLockManager.LockAsync(OrderOperationKey(orderId),
                                            async () =>
                                            {
                                                IOrderStateMachine orderStateMachine = await _orderStateMachineFactory.BuildOrderStateMachineAsync(orderId);
                                                orderStateMachine.ChangePaymentStatus(PaymentStatuses.Completed);
                                                Console.WriteLine($"Consumer - {nameof(PaymentCompletedEvent)} : {_integrationMessagePublisher.IntegrationMessages.Count}");
                                            });
}
```

Information:
I try to consume messages. When I consume a message, different prosedures are called. All prosedures create some messages and add them into message-holder (IIntegrationMessagePublisher). After consume operation is completed, I want to publish all messages.

I have a class called IIntegrationMessagePublisher which holds list of message objects in memory; hence, IIntegrationMessagePublisher has to be a scoped object. When I check message count in consumer, I see the count is 1. However when I check it in filter class, message count is 0. In this case, I think I should not put filter and consumer in the same scope.

Could someone please tell me what I am missing during mass-transit configuration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you delaying the messages? Adding _UseInMemoryOutbox_ will do that for you, and only publish message if the consumer doesn't throw an exception. Then you can just use IPublishEndpoint in your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but this is only a use case. I try to learn how I can use filter and consumer in the same scope.

Comment: Thing is, they should be the same scope if the scope is at the right level. The video in my previous comment on your other question shows where all middleware can be configured, and how it affects the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Startup**

```
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<OrderStateOrchestrator>(
                                          configurator => configurator
                                             .UseFilter(new CustomTransactionFilter<OrderStateOrchestrator>())
                                          )
     .Endpoint(configurator => { configurator.Name = $"{Program.STARTUP_PROJECT_NAME}.{nameof(OrderStateOrchestrator)}"; });


    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(massTransitOption.HostName,
                 massTransitOption.VirtualHost,
                 hst =>
                 {
                     hst.Username(massTransitOption.UserName);
                     hst.Password(massTransitOption.Password);
                 });
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

**Filter**

```
 public class CustomTransactionFilter<TConsumer> :
     IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>> where TConsumer : class
 {
     public async Task Send(ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer> context, IPipe<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>> next)
     {
         var serviceProvider = context.GetPayload<IServiceProvider>();
         var integrationMessagePublisher = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationMessagePublisher>();

         await next.Send(context);
         await integrationMessagePublisher.Publish();
     }

     public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
     {
         context.CreateScope("TransactionFilter");
     }
 }
```

I watched the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4Z5puk4jW4&t=2535s) couple of times and I have figured it out eventually. Is it possible that you could share the code on GitHub? It would make it easier to examine the code.

Thanks for your help @ChrisPatterson